# Codeigniter: Not showing updated values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, lamp

I am using codeigniter. When I update database values using website UI, it gets updated in database but on user interface it shows old values only. After refreshing page it shows updated values.
Please suggest solution on the same.
Thanks.

Comment: You should provide us with more information to be able to help you with your problem. Show us your code... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX. Something like this:

```
    data = {"slug" : slug};
    $.ajax({
         url: '', //url of controller where you would update the code using model
         method: 'POST', //method 
         data: data, //data to be updated
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(res){ //Upadte html; Note the data in 'res' variable is the data which your above 'url' would echo 
    })
    .fail(function(res){//handle here if error occured
    });
```

Hope this is a good starting point for you to learn AJAX. I would have helped you more if you provide us with some code.